# Knockout: Set caption of select after changing observable array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a select bound to a `ko.observableArray()` of property objects:

```
<select title="Select Property"
  data-bind="options: $root.properties,
         optionsCaption: '- Select Property -',
         optionsText: 'name',
         optionsValue: 'typeId',
         value: $root.columns()[index]
  "></select>
```

When there is a selection the select element displays the name that was selected.  That worked fine for a while but now I need to modify the `properties` observableArray after a selection.  As soon as I do that the select reverts back to the optionsCaption.

At the bottom of [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) page is the section

> Note 2: Post-processing the generated options

I think this could help me set the select back to displaying `name` but I haven't figured out how.

Barring that can I use JQuery to grab the select and set the name?

I'm thinking something like:

```
$("select[title='Select Property']").setAttribute();
```

but the select is generated in a ko foreach so I would have to specify the index of the element in order to get it (how?) and even then I'm not sure how to make JQuery play well with knockout.

Did I mention I'm still learning most of this stuff?

Thanks.

------------------ EDIT ------------------

To show how I'm modifying the array:

I'm getting the `newValue` and `oldValue` from `subscribeChanged`, then

```
if (typeof(newValue) != "undefined") {
  var newProperty = model.allProperties[newValue];
  if (model.properties.indexOf(newProperty) != -1) {
    model.properties.splice(model.properties.indexOf(newProperty), 1);
  }
  model.propertiesInUse[newValue] = index;
}

if (typeof(oldValue) != "undefined") {
  var oldProperty = model.allProperties[oldValue];

  if (model.properties.indexOf(oldProperty) == -1) {
    model.properties.unshift(oldProperty);
  }
  if (model.propertiesInUse[oldValue]) {
    delete model.propertiesInUse[oldValue];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your model snippet code where you modify the observableArray ? Out of curiosity, may I know why do you need to modify a dropdown properties which are supposed to be still there ?!

Comment: Hi, I took the weekend off :).  Basically I have a bunch of columns with a dropdown of properties for objects in the rows.  When you select a property to display in one column, that property shouldn't be available in the other columns (no reason to have duplicate columns).  I'm using the `subscribeChanged` function to get the newVal, oldVal from the select and editing the array to remove and add those properties as they're selected/deselected.

Comment: Btw, the subscribeChanged function: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/914

Comment: I am trying to understand what you exactly looking for. Take a look at this and let me know if this is what you want to do. It can be done  with a more efficient way. https://jsfiddle.net/tjzo124x/20/

Comment: That is what I want to do except users can add as many columns as they like and the properties are dynamic and vary based on the object's properties in each row.

Comment: So you're not explicitly setting the value of the `selectedValue` observables?  (`selectedValue1(properties[1])` or some such).  They have no value at first so the display is the options caption.  But the return statement in the subscribeChanged function seems to be setting the selectedValue to that item ... am I correct?

Comment: selectedValue gets set automatically. In subscribeChanged of each selectedValue1 ,2,3 the old value gets inserted to the other observableArray and the new selected value gets removed from the other abservableArray. if you can create a jsfiddle link  of your actual scenario with your sample data and post it (like I did) I might be able to help you with a better solution within next 2~3 hours.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can get working tonight.  I appreciate your fiddle and I may be able to make something work from that.  If you have time post it as an answer.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj: Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyeu2joq/32/.  I need to figure out the best way to add and remove columns.  I'm thinking just add an array of objects like that look like this:  `index: index, array: <array at that index>, value: <value of select element to display>` and just rebuild against that.

Comment: Look at my answer, Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand your case

-You need to make a dynamic dropDown list in a way that any added dropDown gets updated with the values that haven't been selected yet.

-If a dropdown is removed and had a selected value, that value needs to be re-added to other dropDowns.

Below is my approach :

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/251/

HTML :

```
<!-- ko foreach: MainPropertiesList -->
  <select title="Select Property" data-bind="value:SelectedValue">
     <option data-bind="value:'',text:'-Select Property -'"></option>
      <!-- ko foreach: Options -->
        <option data-bind="value:typeId,text:name"></option>
     <!-- /ko -->
  </select>
  <span data-bind="text:'remove',click:$root.deleteColumn"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<hr>
<span data-bind="text:'add',click:$root.addColumn"></span>
```

JS:

```
var data = [{name:"Property1",typeId:1},{name:"Property2",typeId:2},{name:"Property3",typeId:3},{name:"Property4",typeId:4}];

ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeChanged = function (callback, context) {
    var savedValue = this.peek();
    return this.subscribe(function (latestValue) {
        var oldValue = savedValue;
        savedValue = latestValue;
        callback.call(context, latestValue, oldValue);
    });
};

var DropDownItemViewModel = function (index){
  var self = this;
  self.SelectedValue = ko.observable();
  self.Index = ko.observable(index);
  self.Options = ko.observableArray(($.map(data, function (item) {
    return new OptionItemViewModel(item);
  })));

 self.SelectedValue.subscribeChanged(function(newVal, oldValue){
    if(newVal){
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(appVM.MainPropertiesList(), function (item) {
         ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.Options(), function (item2) {
          if(item2 && item2.typeId() == newVal && self.Index() != item.Index() ){
            item.Options.remove(item2);
           if(oldValue){
              item.Options.push(new OptionItemViewModel({name:"Property" + oldValue , typeId : oldValue}));
           }
        }
      });
    });

     ko.utils.arrayForEach(appVM.SelectedPropertiesList(), function (item) {
      if(item && item.typeId() == oldValue){
         appVM.SelectedPropertiesList.remove(item);
      }
    });
    appVM.SelectedPropertiesList.push(new OptionItemViewModel({name:"Property" + newVal , typeId : newVal}));
    }
  });
}
var OptionItemViewModel = function (data){
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.typeId = ko.observable(data.typeId);
}

var AppViewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.numberOfColumns = ko.observable(2);
  self.properties = ko.observableArray();
  self.MainPropertiesList = ko.observableArray();
  self.SelectedPropertiesList = ko.observableArray();
  for (var i = 0; i <= self.numberOfColumns(); i++) {
     self.MainPropertiesList.push(new DropDownItemViewModel(i));
  }
  self.deleteColumn = function(item){
    self.MainPropertiesList.remove(item);
    self.UpdateDropDowns(item);
  }
  self.addColumn = function(){
     self.MainPropertiesList.push(new DropDownItemViewModel(self.MainPropertiesList().length));
     self.UpdateAddedDropDown();
  }
  self.UpdateAddedDropDown = function(){
    var len = self.MainPropertiesList().length ; 
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(appVM.SelectedPropertiesList(), function (item) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.MainPropertiesList()[len-1].Options(), function (item2) {
        if(item && item2 && item.typeId() == item2.typeId()){
            self.MainPropertiesList()[len-1].Options.remove(item2);
        }
       });
    });
  }
  self.UpdateDropDowns = function(data){
    if(data.SelectedValue()){
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.MainPropertiesList(), function (item) {
         item.Options.push(new OptionItemViewModel({name:"Property" + data.SelectedValue() ,typeId:data.SelectedValue()}));
    });
    }
  }
}
var appVM = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(appVM);
```

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic!  So these dropdowns are column headers in a table. When they change, the cells under them are updated too.  Currently there's a row object with an array of columns that correspond to the headers.  I am currently setting them in the subscribe to selectedValue.  Can I still do that in your model?  (I need to really go through it).

Comment: This wasn't a part of your question. Look at the updated example again if I got what exactly you mean. You should be able to add whatever you want to the model that I've suggested.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it is useful -;

Comment: Note there are two sub models for each dropdown.Please try to modify the fiddle and some how fake what you want because I don't get exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You keep bringing a new thing to the table. see if i helps  https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/252/ . You may want to create a new question and explain a little bit more details by showing an image or fiddle and either mention all the possibilities at once or you might be able to handle the rest by your own.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Sorry to be such a pain.  I'll take it from here.